# Is in_irq() reliable?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, kernel, irq

[Unreliable Guide To Hacking The Linux Kernel](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking.html) states that

> You can tell you are in a hardware interrupt, because in_irq() returns true.
>   **Caution**. Beware that this will return a false positive if interrupts are disabled (see below).

Is it really the case that `in_irq()` may return non-zero not in hardirq context in the Linux kernels 2.6.32 or newer on x86?

In my experiments with the kernel 2.6.32 (Debian 6) and 3.4 (OpenSUSE 12.1), `in_irq()` always returned 0 when called from a process context even if it was called between `local_irq_disable()` and `local_irq_enable()`. The results were the same when I used spinlock functions that disable interrupts instead of `local_irq*`.

From the source code of the kernel, I currently cannot see how `in_irq()` can return a false positive. Could anyone clarify this?

EDIT: I have also tried both `*_irqsave()` and `*_irq()` spinlock API as well as `local_irq_save()` / `local_irq_restore()`, the results were the same, that is, `in_irq()` returned 0 when the interrupts were disabled. Disabling the interrupts explicitly via `cli` machine instruction on x86 also did not force in_irq() to return non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

`in_irq()` is a wrapper that [looks at some bits in `preempt_count`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/include/linux/hardirq.h#L77), which is an int in the `thread_info` struct and a value of 0 means it's not pre-empted so it's not in an irq.

`local_irq_disable()` by itself does not affect that count, but [`spin_lock_irqsave()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h#L241) [does](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/include/linux/preempt.h#L30), so that could lead to the false positive. You say you used the spinlock functions, did you use this one? If so, look to see if the value of preempt_count is changing.

EDIT: Just to cover all the bases, check to make sure kernel pre-emption is enabled.

Comment: CONFIG_PREEMPT is 'y', of course. Yes, I checked *_irqsave, *_irq and *_bh variants of spinlock API. In each case, `in_irq()` returned 0 even when a spinlock was locked.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the implementation of `in_irq()`. This is why I do not understand why it does not produce false positives on my machines.

Comment: Does `in_irq()` return non-zero when a spinlock is locked or interrupts are disabled some other way in your experiments?

Comment: I've also failed to get a non-zero from `in_irq()`, or in `preempt_count`. (3.2.0.31)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Well, I will try to dig into that kernel code  further when I have time. A wild guess may be that `in_irq()` is reliable on x86; not sure about ARM, need to investigate that too. But perhaps it could be unrealiable on some other architectures. We'll see. Anyway, thank you for your input.